# PDF reader in android

Tags: android, pdf

I want to ask some questions about PDF reading in Android. please help me
is it possible to make pdf reader with voice in android ?
if yes then which jar/api will help me fir this ? 
please note that my pdf may be with size 60mb to 80mb.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help.

http://andpdf.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/andpdf/trunk/

it is the source code for adobe pdf reader. Now if you want to insert voice output in it you can update this application using TTS (Text to Speech) Class for android.

You can get help about TTS class from this link:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/TextToSpeechActivity.html

Comment: hi, pls describe me how to use this code. how to convert pdf to voice output.?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible, there are a lot of PDF reading/rendering library out there, just pick up the one you like. For the voice, starting with Android 1.6, there's a TTS (Text-To-Speech) API available: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html

Answer (score 0):

Just go through in net, there are some pdf readers in android namely..

Android PDF Viewer
VuDroid
droidreader
android-pdf
APDFViewer
 I think most of these are use JNI(In native load C,C++ library) to render pdf file. So You have to some basic knowledge of how JNI works.

Or If you want to make your own PDF reader then you can use any third party C,C++ library for render PDF file and build a shared library and make a call from your android app (Using JNI) but is to hard work(I know I gone through this process).. :-) All the best..!

Answer (score 0):

Qoppa has an excellent commercial PDF viewer.

Answer (score 0):

You missed Solo PDF reader, the best one in market. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lrmobilabs.pdfreader&hl=en As we can see 5000+ downloads in 2 weeks. Best PDF Reader for your android device, and Its Free