# iText PDF Reader on Android

Tags: android, pdf, itext

is there an simple example for reading a PDF document using iText in  android? it will display the content of pdf document in android. maybe a example that would read "Hello World" inside a PDF and display it in android.

I know I am asking too much but i want to learn from those who experience using iText. I have tried first existing example using itext in android [Example](http://technotransit.wordpress.com/2011/06/17/using-itext-in-android/) but I can't make it work maybe because im using itext version 5.3.3 latest.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: a) iText does not include a PDF viewer and can't display contents of a PDF page on any platfrom (including Android).

Comment: b) iText is now GPL or commerical...   People are still rambling about iText due to mis-information and historical reaons.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Image using iText and then display it in Scroll View.
Please take a look at this link, it will help you creating Images from PDF using iText Library.
[Read or open a PDF file using iText in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291734/read-or-open-a-pdf-file-using-itext-in-android/19151358#19151358)

I hope this helps.